# join two patterns in one preg_match_all

Tags: php, string, pattern-matching, preg-match, preg-match-all

how I can join these two patterns to fit on a single preg_match_all:
I have this:

```
preg_match_all("/(<span[^>]*annot[^>]*value=.?(\w*).?[^>]*>)(.*?)<\/span>/", $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

and this:

```
preg_match_all("/(<span[^>]*value=.?(\w*).?[^>]*annot[^>]*>)(.*?)<\/span>/", $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

I need the pattern to look for two things at once

Comment: you could start by NOT using regexes to try and match html. down that road [lies madness](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068)

Comment: thanks, but you have a better way to do it? did not do it is not a best solution

Comment: what are you trying to do? extract the contents of a couple particular `<span>`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the HTML matching thing, try this:

```
preg_match_all("/((<span[^>]*annot[^>]*value=.?(\w*).?[^>]*>)(.*?)<\/span>|(<span[^>]*value=.?(\w*).?[^>]*annot[^>]*>)(.*?)<\/span>)/", $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

They are just combined via an `or` operator like this:

```
(exp1|exp2)
```

Edit: If I understood what you are trying to do, matching "annot= value=" and "value= annot=", you can use this regexp instead (Hope I didn't mess anything, but you should get the idea):

```
(<span[^>]*(value=.?(\w*).?[^>]*|annot[^>]*)>)(.*?)<\/span>
```

Comment: Did you post this accidentally? You wrote the same comment on the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all("/(<span[^>]*(?:(?:annot|value=.?(\w*).?)|(?:value=.?(\w*).?|annot))[^>]*>)(.*?)<\/span>/", $text, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Anyway, I suggest you to use PHP [Document Object Model][1] instead because it's highly discouraged to use regular expressions to parse HTML data.

```
<?PHP

   $DOM = new DOMDocument;
   $DOM->loadHTML($HTML);

   $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('span');

   foreach ($items as $item)
   {
       foreach ($item->attributes as $attribute)
       {
           if (($attr->nodeName == "name") && ($attr->nodeName == "annotation"))

            //....
?>
```

Comment: sure your answer is correct but I dont get what I need, I've added an example

Comment: Sure it would be better to do so but I need  the initial positionof the spans in the text :(